# Ubuntu 22.04 is not directing to the main desktop screen after starting up

Tags: 22.04, workspaces, ubuntu-gnome

Every time, I start up my Ubuntu, I always need to click this workspace screen in order to get the main desktop. How do I get rid of this? After starting  up, I want it to direct me to the main desktop, not to this screen where there is a search box.

[image: Please see screenshot]